# Arduino CDC dropping data

Tags: arduino, cdc

I am trying to send a bunch of data using Serial.write(buff,len) (via USB virtual serial port) with an ATmega32U4. I originally wrote my application using LUFA and it worked great. However, I now ported it to Arduino and it's dropping data.

The relevant code is

```
void uartTask() {
  static unsigned long timer = 0;
  if (Serial) { // does the data have somewhere to go?
    uint16_t ct = RingBuffer_GetCount(&serialBuffer);
    unsigned long curTime = millis();
    if (ct > 64 || (timer-curTime > 100)) { // is there data to send?
      timer = curTime;
      if (serialBuffer.Out + ct <= serialBuffer.End) { // does it loop in our buffer?
        ct = Serial.write(serialBuffer.Out, ct); // dump all the date
        serialBuffer.Out += ct;
        if (serialBuffer.Out == serialBuffer.End)
          serialBuffer.Out = serialBuffer.Start; // loop the buffer
      } 
      else { // it looped the ring buffer
        uint8_t* loopend = serialBuffer.Out + ct;
        uint16_t ct2 = loopend - serialBuffer.End;
        uint16_t ct1 = ct - ct2;
        uint16_t ct1s = Serial.write(serialBuffer.Out, ct1); // dump first block
        if (ct1s == ct1) {
          ct2 = Serial.write(serialBuffer.Start, ct2); // dump second block
          serialBuffer.Out = serialBuffer.Start + ct2; // update the pointers
          ct = ct1+ct2;
        } 
        else {
          ct = ct1s;
          serialBuffer.Out += ct;
        }
      }

        uint_reg_t CurrentGlobalInt = GetGlobalInterruptMask();
        GlobalInterruptDisable();

        serialBuffer.Count -= ct; // update the count

        SetGlobalInterruptMask(CurrentGlobalInt);

    }

    if (RingBuffer_GetCount(&serialBuffer) < 256) {
      SET(TX_BUSY, LOW); // re-enable the serial port
      serialRXEnable();
    }

    int16_t w;
    while ((w = Serial.read()) >= 0) {
      Serial_SendByte(w);
    }
  }
}

ISR(USART1_RX_vect) { // new serial data!
  RingBuffer_Insert(&serialBuffer, UDR1 ); // save it
  if (serialBuffer.Count > 1000) // are we almost out of space?
    SET(TX_BUSY, HIGH); // signal we can't take any more
  if (serialBuffer.Count > 1020) 
    serialRXDisable(); // if our flag is ignored disable the serial port so it doesn't clog things up
}
```

I've used almost identical code with LUFA and it never drops data. I am running Ubuntu on my PC.

This is basically just a USB to serial converter. As serial data arrives it fires the interrupt that puts the data in a ringbuffer that is later read and sent over USB.

I can't figure out why the LUFA based code would work but the Arduino doesn't. I would think that checking the return values of Serial.write() would let you know if your data didn't make it all the way.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that only one program has the serial device open?

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly when I use standalone code instead of the Arduino IDE. If I reduce the buffer size to 256 and apply the bug fix from https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/1945 it seems to work. However, with larger buffers it still fails.